# Why does this shell script insert single quotes into a command?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the following shell script to build something:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

SRC_DIR=$1

cd $SRC_DIR

rm CMakeCache.txt
cmake \
-DCGAL_DIR=/src/path \
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=" -frounding-math -std=c++11 " \
-DTBB_INSTALL_DIR=/tbb/dir \
-DTBB_ARCH_PLATFORM=tbb_arch \
.

make VERBOSE=1
```

Now, option -x will show me the commands issued by the script. The call to `cmake` looks as follows:

> cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/src/path '-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -frounding-math
>   -std=c++11 ' -DTBB_INSTALL_DIR=/tbb/dir -DTBB_ARCH_PLATFORM= tbb_arch .

The call is processed without an error message, *but* observe the single quotes `'` around `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=...`.

**Where do they come from? What's their effect?**

Comment: Single quotes are shown in trace output when `bash` finds an argument containing whitespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes are shown in trace output when bash finds an argument containing whitespaces.

Examples:

```
bash -cx 'echo foo "xyz 123"'
+ echo foo 'xyz 123'
foo xyz 123

bash -cx "echo foo 'xyz 123'"
+ echo foo 'xyz 123'
foo xyz 123
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Bash's way to enclose parameters containing whitespace in quotes in the trace. Consider this example:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

echo Test "Test" " Test" "Test " ' Test '
```

Output:

```
+ echo Test Test ' Test' 'Test ' ' Test '
Test Test  Test Test   Test
```

It's just an irritating mismatch of provided vs. echoed content. As long as your `cmake` command is executed with the right parameters this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between

```
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=" -frounding-math -std=c++11 "
```

and

```
'-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -frounding-math -std=c++11 '
```

They're two ways of writing the same thing. Bash doesn't remember how you wrote it. Internally it stores each token in an array with the quotes removed. When it prints them it only knows that this one has spaces, so it had better quote it.